# About SelectedIndex property in a DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, events, drop-down-menu

Sorry for my ignorance, but I've always believed that setting the `SelectedIndex` property of a `DropDownList` the `SelectedIndexChanged` event is fired... Am I wrong?

Searching in the documentation I haven't found anything clear...

Thanks

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it cannot fire the selectionchange event.

if you are settting programatically than it not fire the selectionchange event.

Answer (score 0):

[DropDownlist Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx)       [**Selected Index Changed Event**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx) fires when the selection from the list control changes between posts to the server.
Please make sure about following to fire the event.

1. **AutoPostBack**="true"   [**How to use DropDownList AutoPostBack feature**](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-to-use-dropdownlist-autopostback.html)
2. **onselectedindexchanged**="Name of the Handler"

Below is the code.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
onselectedindexchanged="ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged">
   <asp:ListItem Text ="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text ="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>


protected void ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

**Note** - On setting the index at runtime will never fire the event.

Please go through the following links as well.

[**How to: Respond to Changes in List Web Server Controls**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wd7hsyy%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[**How to use DropDownList AutoPostBack feature**](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-to-use-dropdownlist-autopostback.html)